# Implementation of ajax+djangorestframework doesn't work 500

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I am using djangorestframework in order to implement ajax post request.

But unfortunately it doesn't work. Djangorest docs say that I can use default serialisation and return data in this way but it doesn't work. Is my code correct? Or the only way to use ajax with djangorestframework is to create its own serialiser ?

```
@api_view(['POST', ])
def live_search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        key = request.data['key']
        result = Event.objects.filter(title__contains=key)
        result_s = serializers.serialize('json', result)
        request.data['result'] = result_s
    else:
        error = "error"
        return error
    return Response(request.data)
```

As far as it's request, I only know that it's 500 server-side error. Queryset is correct

Answer (score 2):

```
@api_view(['POST', ])
def live_search(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    data = request.data
    key = data.get('key')
    result = Event.objects.filter(title__contains=key)
    result_s = serializers.serialize(result, many=True).data               
    return Response({'result': result_s})
```

Yoh have to declare serializers on header

Comment: doesn't work unfortunately . and what is the purpose of .data?

Comment: it will return json data otherwise it returns object

Comment: didn't help. still 500

Comment: DEBUG = True please open in setting file so that you will get error in console

Comment: debug is true in settings.py, and I don't get any errors in console. actually never when accessing views.py functions by ajax request

Comment: you can use print command first line of function,if print not works then it can be issue of ajax request not found live_search

Comment: by the way data.get('key') doesn't work only how I did it